# Looper/Handler vs. Executor

Tags: java, android

Why use Looper/Handler when I could use an Executor method(s)?

The Looper/Handler duo seems rather clunky and doesn't seem to do a great deal beyond allowing the queuing of runnables and seemingly has less flexibility.

What was the looper design rationale?

Thanks.

Comment: `Looper` and `Handler` are mostly there in support of the main application thread. You are welcome to use them for other threads, and occasionally there will be cause for that (see `LocationManager`). However, having used a `HandlerThread` before, a `ThreadPoolExecutor` would be my choice for background work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A looper by itself does not have many advantages over an executor. It is how Android manages worker. But you are able to get the main thread of your app with `Looper.getMainLooper()`, this can have the following advantages:

- You can change the ui from the MainLooper, (only do if not a compute intense background task, since you would freeze the UI)
- Execute Runnables "in-sync" with the all the other native tasks. Meaning you post your Runnable in the same queue as android does
- No need to create a thread yourself. You can use the already running Looper.