# Is using Looper.myLopper() or null in FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates() the same thing?

Tags: android, android-looper, fusedlocationproviderclient

I'm creating a location tracking app for which I'm using the `FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates()` method. One of its argument requires a `Looper` object and I'm not completely sure how it works. Right now I'm just passing `null` to it and it works as expected.

After researching I learned that the UI Thread is basically a `HandlerThread` which already has its own Looper object (I know basic stuff but realized a bit late). So I used `Looper.myLooper(`) instead of null this time and it still works.

```
private void getLocationUpdates(){
//checkSelfPermissions
fusedLocationProviderClient
.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback,Looper.myLooper());
}
```

The documentation says that passing `null` executes the locationCallback on the calling thread. So what happens when I use `Looper.myLooper()`. Does both have the same effect when calling from literally any thread or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a bit more info from the [document](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback,%20android.os.Looper)):
`Callbacks for LocationCallback will be made on the specified thread, which must already be a prepared looper thread.`

Before you could understand the differences between passing `null` and `looper` as the value 3rd parameter, what you need to know are: `looper` / `handler` / `HandlerThread` (because you mentioned HandlerThread, so I put it here together with the other two).

There are a lot of articles about these concepts, here are some just FYI:

- [Understanding Android Core: Looper, Handler, and HandlerThread](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a)
- [Android: Looper, Handler, HandlerThread. Part I.](https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/)
- [Explanation of handler, looper and related android thread classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42801646/853191)
- [Looper/Handler vs. Executor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25633172/853191)

---

So I hope I can try to answer as simple as possible.

When you say:
`I'm creating a location tracking app for which I'm using the FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates() method. One of its argument requires a Looper object and I'm not completely sure how it works. Right now I'm just passing null to it and it works as expected.`

I assume you didn't start any new thread (e.g.: no `new Thread()` or no `new HandlerThread()`) at that time, if so, it's very possible you're calling the method `getLocationUpdates()` in Android main thread, i.e.: the default thread, the one on which you can update the view (such as by default you can run `textView.setText("xx")` without any problem, this is because you're in main thread - a.k.a. UI thread, by default), so passing `null` will execute the callback on the `calling thread`, i.e.: the main thread. And for now you need to know, main thread has a looper, we can call it main looper.

Then you say:
`After researching I learned that the UI Thread is basically a HandlerThread which already has its own Looper object (I know basic stuff but realized a bit late). So I used Looper.myLooper() instead of null this time and it still works.`

I assume you did something like below:

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread();
getLocationUpdates();

private void getLocationUpdates(){
//checkSelfPermissions
fusedLocationProviderClient
.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback,Looper.myLooper());
}
```

This time you passed `Looper.myLooper()` as the 3rd param.

Yes by this way, you provided a `looper`, and the `locationCallback` will be executed on the specific thread of that `looper` (talk a bit about looper later).

Because, however, it's very possible you're calling `getLocationUpdates()` in the main thread again, so the `Looper.myLooper` still returns the looper in main thread, yes you can consider the `callback` is still running at main looper, the same as you set `null` above.

However, if you change the code a bit like this:

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread();
handlerThread.start();
getLocationUpdates(handlerThread.getLooper());

private void getLocationUpdates(Looper looper){
//checkSelfPermissions
fusedLocationProviderClient
.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, looper);
}
```

The `callback` will be executed on the specified looper thread, i.e.: the looper object you get from `handler.getLooper()`.

So what's difference on earth?

When you create a new `HandlerThread` and start it, you're starting a new `Thread`, and `handlerThread.start()` will call the `HandlerThread#run()` by default, at where the handler thread creates a new `looper`, and this looper is prepared, tied with the `handlerThread` you created just now.

You'll see the real difference if you are trying to update UI elements (such as update textview or mapview) in the callback. Because UI updating is allowed on UI thread only, if you set `handlerThread.getLooper()` then you will be running into exception when trying to update UI; and there will be no problem if you set `null` or `Looper.myLooper()` **from the main thread**, reason for emphasis on `main thread` is because, `Looper.myLooper` will reference to different looper object when running on different threads.

Talk a bit about looper: With the `looper` object, you can new a handler and pass the looper to it like: `Handler handler = new Handler(looper)`, then when you call `handler.post(new Runnable(...))`, the runnable will be executed on the looper thread which you set on the handler, I think that's what the API did behind the scenes.

Read more articles about `handler` / `looper` / `HandlerThread` will be helpful I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling *getLocationUpdates* method in the Main thread then *locationCallback* would be also executed in the Main thread.
If you are calling *getLocationUpdates* in background thread with passed null as a looper your callback would be executed in background thread.
It depends on your needs do you exactly need to specify in which thread your callback is executed.